# remove NIC via Qemu monitor

Tags: qemu

I’m attempting to remove this network device from a Qemu guest:

```
(qemu) info network
info network
…
idRygZ1D: index=0,type=nic,model=virtio-net-pci,macaddr=02:00:00:00:20:06
 \ idU3WwDX: index=0,type=tap,fd=36

(qemu) info pci
info pci
…
  Bus  0, device   7, function 0:
    Ethernet controller: PCI device 1af4:1000
      IRQ 11.
      BAR0: I/O at 0xc0a0 [0xc0bf].
      BAR1: 32 bit memory at 0xfebd4000 [0xfebd4fff].
      BAR6: 32 bit memory at 0xffffffffffffffff [0x0003fffe].
      id "idRygZ1D"
```

However, after executing:

```
(qemu) netdev_del idU3WwDX 
netdev_del idU3WwDX
(qemu) device_del idRygZ1D 
device_del idRygZ1D
```

The device is still listed in the pci and network infos as well
as from `lspci` inside the guest. Curiously, subsequent
invocations of `netdev_del` whereas `device_del` succeeds
without having an observable effect:

```
(qemu) netdev_del idU3WwDX 
netdev_del idU3WwDX
Device 'idU3WwDX' not found
(qemu) device_del idRygZ1D
device_del idRygZ1D
(qemu) device_del idRygZ1D
device_del idRygZ1D
```

Something is not right, I assume. What’s the correct approach to
removing a NIC from the device table?

*EDIT*: The silence of `device_del` is probably irrelevant
because the corresponding handler `qmp_device_del()` does not
emit a message if it cannot match the given id to a device, which
`qmp_netdev_del()` does.

*EDIT 2*: In the guest, I do get a `RTM_NEWLINK` event over
netlink for `netdev_del $NETID` similar to `set_link $NETID
off`. Still the device remains in the list of PCI devices.